# is cpu_online_mask integer value

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, arm64

There is this, cpu_online_mask macro defined in Linux Kernel, wanted to know what does it return?
does it return some integer value?

```
#define cpu_online_mask   ((const struct cpumask *)&__cpu_online_mask)
```

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/cpumask.h#L96

or does it return a pointer to cpumask struct

```
typedef struct cpumask { DECLARE_BITMAP(bits, NR_CPUS); } cpumask_t;
```

so that DECLARE_BITMAP(bits, NR_CPUS) = cpu_online_mask  ??

I didn't understand how member of struct "cpumask" DECLARE_BITMAP(bits, NR_CPUS) is initialized ?

Comment: It returns a pointer to `struct cpumask` which just contains enough longs to hold one bit per cpu.

Answer (score 0):

> is cpu_online_mask integer value

No.

> wanted to know what does it return?

A pointer to constant `struct cpumask`.

> does it return some integer value?

No.

> does it return a pointer to cpumask struct

Yes!

> o that DECLARE_BITMAP(bits, NR_CPUS) = cpu_online_mask ?

No. It's just [DECLARE_BITMAP from types.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/types.h#L10). You could say that `DECLARE_BITMAP(bits, NR_CPUS)` defines `cpu_online_mask->bits` member.

> how member of struct "cpumask" DECLARE_BITMAP(bits, NR_CPUS) is initialized ?

The variable `__cpu_online_mask` has [no initializer in kernel/cpu.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/cpu.c#L2591).

*** The macro `cpu_online_mask` does not really "return" anything, the token in source code `cpu_online_mask` is literally replaced by the result of expansion. For example code like `cpu_online_mask->bits[0] = 1;` is *replaced* by `((const struct cpumask *)&__cpu_online_mask)->buts[0] = 1;` and then compiled.